# Docker for windows, doesn't wor

Tags: docker, windows-10

Recently, I had problems with launching the docker. After a few resets and reinstallations, it fired. Then the same thing today, after a long torment, I was able to start it, so that after restart the computer it would not start again.

[image: an error]

Comment: Show me your logs

Answer (score 0):

If enybody have this same problem. Do not click quit, but cross in the corner and go to options and uncheck WLS2. This work for me.